# Получение состояния кнопки мыши в XNA

Tags: c#, разработка-игр, xna, xna-4

отлавливаю клик мышки:

```
if (Mouse.GetState().LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed) {
i++;
}
```

И дело в том, что i прибавляется до тех пор пока я не отпущу кнопку мыши. Можно ли как-то сделать это нажатие одноразовым?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно можно. По сути вы пытаетесь отловить переход из состояния кнопки из "отпущена" в "нажата". Но для этого вам никак не обойтись без запоминания предыдущего состояния кнопки:

```
private static MouseState mouse_prev;
private static MouseState mouse_curr;
```

А в вашем цикле должно быть примерно так:

```
mouse_prev = mouse_curr;
mouse_curr = Mouse.GetState();
if(mouse_prev.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released && mouse_curr.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
{
    i++;
}
```